# How to set value for specific row and specific column

Tags: angular

If i have this:

```
datas = new Array(10);
data1 = new Array (4);
<tr *ngFor="let data of datas">
<td *ngFor="let e of data1>{{e}}</td>
</tr>
```

How can i set value for  third row and second column? Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you be more specific with `datas` and `data1`

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Do you want the arrays to have some value on `|3,4|` or do you want to print something at there? If you want the arrays to have a value, you better do it in the component rather than in the template.

Comment: You need the second array to be a property of the class contained within the first array.

Comment: To set or to get ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
 <tr *ngFor=“let data of datas;let i=index;”>
 <td *ngFor=“let e of data1;let j=index”>{{ i==2 && j== 1 ? dosomethinghere : donothing}}</td>
</tr>
```